# Cross domain WCF access

Tags: asp.net, wcf, json, web-services, jsonp

I have been using WCF web services for around about a year now and have found them very useful. I have always used and consumed them on the same serving domain. However this time I am wanting to consume them on another domain. I understand why this is happening, because of security and so. I had the same problem with reading RSS feeds from an external domain.

I have been doing some research into this and most people are saying that JSONP (padded JSON) will solve this problem but I thought i'd ask my own question because someone might have found another answer or because i'm using .NET 4, the answer might be simpler.

So, I am using Jquery to consume these restful web services on another domain. I am also using .NET 4. My web services are a mix of GET and POST so really i'm looking for a solution that will deal with both GET and POSTS across domains. Does anyone have a solution or examples for this? My WCF web services are located within my ASP.NET web application. I have also turned on crossdomainscriptaccessenabled in my web config.

Also, for what it's worth - when I was setting up WCF web sevices last year, I was able to consume a web service on an iphone app which now confuses me as I never enabled cross domain posting. That's just a side note though.

Thanks

Comment: Consuming WCF service on multiple clients is the point; the cross-domain issue only comes into play when you consume from javascript/silverlight/flash/flex *hosted* on another domain. Your iPhone app has no hosting domain, so there is no cross-domain problem.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense to me. I was trying to work out why it worked on my iphone app. Thanks for clearing that up Nate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you require POST, JSONP probably won't cut it. Since it works by injecting a `<script>` reference to the third-party resource, JSONP is inherently limited to GET requests.

Depending on your [browser support requirements](http://caniuse.com/cors), CORS allows you full access to cross-domain services. jQuery 1.5+ has great support for CORS. You only need to add an HTTP header or two to your WCF domain's responses to enable it.

A less elegant solution that doesn't require browser support is to [use a server-side HTTP proxy on the domain where the services will be called from](http://encosia.com/use-asp-nets-httphandler-to-bridge-the-cross-domain-gap/). Using that approach, server-side code makes the cross-domain request on behalf of the browser and relays the response back. That circumvents the same-origin restriction at the browser, but does add some overhead to the process.

To clarify your confusion about the iPhone app previously working, keep in mind that the cross-domain restriction is one that browsers impose as part of their implementation of XMLHttpRequest. It is not a restriction imposed by WCF itself. A native app running on an iPhone would be able to freely access your service without modification, similar to how a Silverlight app in the browser would be able to (however, a web app running on the iPhone would run into the same trouble you are).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Dave. It might be better if I explain what it is i'm trying to do. I have a web site called web site a and another web site, b. They are both running on the same server. Web site b is the admin system to web site a. web site b was just a folder within web site a but now i'm separating them into different applications to make things easier (or so I thought at the time). All the web services are stored on web site a. They are seperate domains but on the same server. Do you think that would help?

Comment: Yeah so going back to your answer. I don't think JSONP would solve this because I will be needed the POST method. In terms of browser support, web site b will only be accessed privately by myself and my colleagues as an 'intranet' type application. So browser support will be fine as we will be using up to date browsers such as Google Chrome. Based on your answer, I think CORS looks to be the most suitable solution so I will look into this right now and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: @codemonkey: The same-origin restriction is based on the URI of the service, not where it's physically hosted. Any differences between the page's URL and the service's URL before the first forward slash will prevent a traditional XHR request (i.e. domain.com, domain.com:8080, and api.domain.com are all different "origins").

Comment: @codemonkey: Yes, if you're using Chrome, then CORS is definitely the way to go. It's easy to set up, doesn't require any code modification on the service, and is almost transparent when you're using a library that supports it well (like jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

This question sounds like this one: [Weighing Cross Domain Javascript Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244744/weighing-cross-domain-javascript-options/). Maybe the answers there will help you too.